# How can I handle the error, Only one type of resume option is allowed, but multiple were found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using a replicated MongoDB database, and listen to change streams from my app. I use the following code to set this up and listen to a test table:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs'
let client = new MongoClient(url, {
  keepAlive: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 60000,    
  socketTimeoutMS: 60000, 
 })
try {
  let dbclient = await client.connect()
  console.log(dbclient)
  const db = dbclient.db('test')
  const collection = db.collection('accounts')
  const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline)
  changeStream.on('change', function(change) {
    console.log('changed', change)
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('mongo err:', err)
}
```

However occasionally, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught MongoError: Only one type of resume option is allowed, but multiple were found.

This has occurred twice in the past 3 days, after the app has been idle for some time. I am not aware of any way to replicate it.

I am not finding any information on this error aside from [this JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2987), which I am not sure has the same root cause or not to my issue. I am using the latest version of mongodb available on npm.

How can I catch this error and properly handle it?

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this issue?